# ClassCastException (Convert an object to list)

Tags: android, casting, type-conversion, classcastexception, typeconverter

tinydb supports Listobject and object. I store this value as object.

```
private List<List<Restaurant.Menu>> menus = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<Object> objMenus = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < menus.size(); i++)
{
     objMenus.add(menus.get(i));
}
tinydb.putListObject("menusObject",objMenus);
```

Now, I want to convert this object to `List<List<Restaurant.Menu>>` again.

```
private List<List<Restaurant.Menu>> menus = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<Object> objMenus = new ArrayList<>();

objMenus = tinydb.getListObject("menusObject", Object.class);

for (Object list : objMenus)
{
      menus.add((List<Restaurant.Menu>)list);
}

Log.i("XXXHEREXXX",menus.get(0).get(0).name);
```

It works well until log.i(). If I call a value in list, It gives ClassCastException error.
I tried several methods but they are not efficient. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried `String.valueOf(menus.get(0).get(0).name)` ?

Comment: Yes, the same problem :)